# JavaScript time of hoisting

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript does hoisting occur before or after the creation of the `ExecutionContext` associated with the function?

I presume before, if so when?

```
function foo() {
 bar();
 var x; // When is this hoisted?
 function x() {} // ...and when is this hoisted?
};

foo();
```

**Edit:** put another way, I believe a graph of objects is instantiated according to the nesting of scopes in the program code, before a single line of code is run. Is the hoisting information stored in this object graph before runtime?

Comment: Hoisted to where, it's already at the top of it's scope ?

Comment: I presume the hoisting logic runs regardless. I'll update the code so they are not at the top of the scope.

Comment: What do you mean by creation of the ExecutionContext. Like when you can start doing stuff in foo()? You can do console.log(x) right at the top of foo() as long as x is defined as a var (then x will be undefined at the top) or function (then x will be that function) someplace later within foo(). In chrome, functions seem to get hoisted before vars but vars seem to overshadow functions after their definition line. You can try and play with something like `(function(){ console.log(x); var x=54; console.log(x); function x(){}; console.log(x); })()` to see for yourself.

Comment: If you are interested in depth JS this blog is for you http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ it talks about all this stuff in depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hoisting happens as part of *establishing* the execution context:

> #### [[[Call]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)
>
> When the [[Call]] internal method for a Function object *F* is called with a this value and a list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *funcCtx* be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of *F*'s [[FormalParameters]] internal property, the passed arguments List *args*, and the this value as described in [10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3).
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the *FunctionBody* that is the value of *F*'s [[Code]] internal property. If *F* does not have a [[Code]] internal property or if its value is an empty *FunctionBody*, then *result* is (normal, undefined, empty).
> 3. [...]

So, when a function is executed, first its execution context is created and then the function body is evaluated. How that happens is described in section 10.4.3:

> #### [Entering Function Code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)
>
> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object *F*, a caller provided *thisArg*, and a caller provided *argumentsList*:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if *thisArg* is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.
> 3. Else if Type(*thisArg*) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(*thisArg*).
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to *thisArg*.
> 5. Let *localEnv* be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of F as the argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to *localEnv*.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to *localEnv*.
> 8. Let *code* be the value of F’s [[Code]] internal property.
> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code *code* and *argumentsList* as described in [10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5).

The hoisting happens in **step 9** and is explained in detail in [section 10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5). Specifically:

> 5. For each *FunctionDeclaration f* in *code*, in source text order do ...
>   [...]
>   8. For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn* *d* in *code*, in source text order do ...

So function declarations are hoisted before variable declarations.